# Customizing positions of application windows when launching using plists or defaults

Tags: terminal, command-line, plist, defaults, customization

I would like to change the screen position where apps open their windows when launching. I've tried editing the `defaults` values in several ways, but the changes are never saved. Take for example the app Monolingual. If I run:

`plutil -p "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual/Data/Library/Preferences/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual.plist"`

or

`defaults read -app Monolingual`

I get:

```
{
  "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" => "243 325 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 "
  "SUHasLaunchedBefore" => 1
  "SULastCheckTime" => 2021-08-03 15:30:17 +0000
}
```

I would like the change the position to the top left of the screen, which in my case would be coordinates `{0,23}`. Therefore I'd want the `"NSWindow Frame MainWindow"` value to read: `"0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 "`

I've tried various approaches, such as:

`plutil -replace "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" -string "0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 " "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual/Data/Library/Preferences/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual.plist"`

`defaults write com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" "0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 "`

`defaults write com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" -string "0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 "`

`plutil -replace "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" -string "0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027 " "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual/Data/Library/Preferences/com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual.plist"`

After each of these commands, reading the keypath using `defaults read` produces the changes I'd like, however none of these changes persist when the app is launched, and it remains in the same place as before. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If the **PLIST** _file_  is in  `"$HOME/Library/Containers/...` I'm pretty sure that  `defaults write com.github.IngmarStein.Monolingual "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" -string "0 23 429 451 0 0 1680 1027"` is not going to write to it there. It would write to `~/Library/Preferences/...`. That said, you could also try `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`, however, in many cases editing the **PLIST** _file_ of an _application_ with a _command line utility_ requires the target _application_ to be closed and a logout/login or restart. I use various other methods to have my _windows_ where I want them.

Comment: I use both [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) and [**EventScripts**](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) to watch for an _application_ to _activate/deactivate_ and then perform various _actions_, such as _window size/placement_, etc.